# Canvas keep ignoring Paint in drawBitmap method

Tags: android

I would like to draw bitmap(with specified color) on canvas.

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

// create bitmap

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Well, the bitmap is visible on the canvas, but color of drawable didn't change.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to draw bitmap(with specified color) on canvas.

A bitmap contains an image and drawing an image in single color doesn't make any sense. What do you expect it to do? Draw a red rectangle? Shapes can be drawn with color, not images...

The `Color` attribute of your `Paint` will be ignored. That `Paint` parameter is used to pass other settings such as anti-aliasing.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does sense for me, because I have quite complicated image, that I would like to cover with some color (dynamic). Now I have to use canvas.drawLine() & paint to reach this effect.

Comment: Well actually that is not completely true, you can use a `Config.ALPHA_8` bitmap as a mask, and then use paint with color on it

Answer (score 2):

`paint.setColor(Color.RED)` is irrelevant. If your image comes with an alpha channel and you want it to be drawn in a single color, use `ColorFilter` instead:

```
paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: just what I was after +1.
Missing a parenthesis though.